# How to correctly use intrincSize in custom UIView. Where/when to calculate and to update the size?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

I have been trying to understand and utilize `intrinsicSize` on a custom `UIView` for some days now. So far with little success.

The post is quite long, sorry for that :-) Problem is, that the topic is quite complex. While I know that there might be other solutions, I simply want to understand how `intrinsicSize` can be used correctly.

So when someone knows a good source for a in depth explanation on how to use / implement `intrinsicSize` you can skip all my questions and just leave me link.

**My goal:**

Create a custom `UIView` which uses `intrinsicSize` to let AutoLayout automatically adopt to different content. Just like a `UILabel` which automatically resizes depending on its text content, font, font size, etc.

As an example assume a simple view `RectsView` which does nothing but drawing a given number of rects of a given size with given spacing. If not all rects fit into a single row, the content is wrapped and drawing is continued in another row. Thus the height of the view depends on the different properties (number of rects, rects size, spacing, etc.)

This is very much like a `UILabel` but instead of words or letters simple rects are drawn. However, while `UILabel` works perfectly I was not able to achive the same for my `RectsView`.

**Why intrinsicSize**

As @DonMag pointed out in his excellent answers to my previous question, I do not have to use `intrinsicSize` to achieve my goal. I could also use subviews and add constraints to create such a rect pattern. Or I could use a `UICollectionView`, etc.

While this might certainly work, I think it would add a lot of overhead. If the goal would be to recreate a `UILabel` class, one would not use AutoLayout or a CollectionView to arrange the letters to words, would one? Instead one would certainly try to draw the letters manually... Especially when using the `RectsView` in a TableView or a CollectionView a plain view with direct drawing is certainly better than a complex solution compiled of tons of subviews arranged using AutoLayout.

Of course this is an extreme example. However, at the bottom line there are cases where using `intrinsicSize` is certainly the better option. Since `UILabel` and other build in views uses `intrinsicSize` perfectly, there has to be a way to get this working and I just want to know how :-)

**My understanding of intrinsic Size**

@DonMag suspected, that *"I do not really understanding what intrinsicContentSize does and does not do"*. He is most likely correct :-) However, the problem is that I found no source which really explains it...  Thus I have spend several hours trying to understand how to correctly use `intrinsicSize` without little progress.

This is what I have learned [from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW1):

- `intrinsicSize` is a feature used in `AutoLayout`. Views which offer an intrinsic height and/or width do not need to specify constraints for these values.
- There is no guarantee that the view will exactly get its `intrinsicSize`. It is more like a way to tell autoLayout which size would be best for the view while autoLayout will calculate the actual size.
- The calculation is done using the `intrinsicSize` and the `Compression Resistance` + `Content Hugging` properties.
- The calculation of the `intrinsicSize` should only depend on the content, not of the views frame.

**What I do not understand:**

- How can the calculation be independend from the views frame? Of course the `UIImageView` can use the size of its image but the height of a `UILabel` can obviously only be calculated depending on its content AND its width. **So how could my `RectsView` calculate its height without considering the frames width?**
- When should the calculation of the `intrinsicSize` happen? In my example of the `RectsView` the size depends on rect size, spacing and number. In a `UILabel` the size also depends on multiple properties like text, font, font size, etc. If the calculation is done when setting each property it will be performed multiple times which is quite inefficient. So what is the right place to do it?

**Example implementation:**

Here is a simple implementation of my `RectsView`:

```
@IBDesignable class RectsView: UIView {
    
    // Properties which determin the intrinsic height
    @IBInspectable public var rectSize: CGFloat = 20 {
        didSet {
            calcContent()
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable public var rectSpacing: CGFloat = 10 {
        didSet {
            calcContent()
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable public var rowSpacing: CGFloat = 5 {
        didSet {
            calcContent()
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable public var rectsCount: Int = 20 {
        didSet {
            calcContent()
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    
    // Calculte the content and its height
    private var rects = [CGRect]()
    func calcContent() {
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        var y: CGFloat = 0
        
        rects = []
        if rectsCount > 0 {
            for _ in 0..<rectsCount {
                let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: rectSize, height: rectSize)
                rects.append(rect)
                
                x += rectSize + rectSpacing
                if x + rectSize > frame.width {
                    x = 0
                    y += rectSize + rowSpacing
                }
            }
        }
        
        height = y + rectSize
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    
    // Intrinc height
    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 50
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: height)
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    
    // Drawing
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
                
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        
        for rect in rects {
            context?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            context?.fill(rect)
        }
        
        
        let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)]
        let text = "\(height)"
        
        text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), withAttributes: attrs)
    }
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    let CellId = "CellId"

    // Dummy content with different values per row
    var data: [(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, Int)] = [
        (10.0, 15.0, 13.0, 35),
        (20.0, 10.0, 16.0, 28),
        (30.0, 5.0, 19.0, 21)
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "IntrinsicCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellId)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellId, for: indexPath) as? IntrinsicCell ?? IntrinsicCell()
        
        // Dummy content with different values per row
        cell.rectSize = data[indexPath.row].0     // CGFloat((indexPath.row+1) * 10)
        cell.rectSpacing = data[indexPath.row].1  // CGFloat(20 - (indexPath.row+1) * 5)
        cell.rowSpacing = data[indexPath.row].2   // CGFloat(10 + (indexPath.row+1) * 3)
        cell.rectsCount = data[indexPath.row].3   // (5 - indexPath.row) * 7
        
        return cell
    }

    // Add/remove content when tapping on a row
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        var rowData = data[indexPath.row]
        rowData.3 = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? rowData.3 + 5 : rowData.3 - 5)
        data[indexPath.row] = rowData
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}


// Simple cell holing an intrinsic rectsView
class IntrinsicCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private var rectsView: RectsView!
        
    var rectSize: CGFloat {
        get { return rectsView.rectSize }
        set { rectsView.rectSize = newValue }
    }
    
    var rectSpacing: CGFloat {
        get { return rectsView.rectSpacing }
        set { rectsView.rectSpacing = newValue }
    }
    
    var rowSpacing: CGFloat {
        get { return rectsView.rowSpacing }
        set { rectsView.rowSpacing = newValue }
    }
    
    var rectsCount: Int {
        get { return rectsView.rectsCount }
        set { rectsView.rectsCount = newValue }
    }
}
```

**Problems:**

Basicly the `intrinsicSize` works fine: When the TableView is rendered for the first time each row has a different height depending on its intrinsic content. However, the size is not correctly, since the `intrinsicSize` is calculated before the TableView actually layouts its subviews. Thus the `RectsView`s calculate their content size using the default width instead of there acutal, final width.

**So: When/Where to calculate the initial layout?**

Additionally updates to the properties (= tapping on the cells) are not handled correctly

**So: When/Where to calculate the updated layout?**

[image]

Again: Sorry for the long post and thank you very much if you have managed to read until here. I really appreciate  that!

I you know any good source / tutorial / howto which explains all this, I happy about any link you can provide!

**UPDATE: Some more observations**

I have added some debug output to my `RectsView` and to a `UILabel` subclass to see how `intrinsicContentSize` is used.

In `RectsView` `intrinsicContentSize` is called only once before the bounds are set to their final size. Since at this point I not not know the final size yet, I can only calculate the intrinsic size based on the old, outdated width which leads to a wrong result.

In `UIView` however, `intrinsicContentSize` is called multiple times (**why?**) and in the last call, the result seems to be fitting the upcoming, final size. How can this size be known at this point?

```
RectsView willSet frame: (-120.0, -11.5, 240.0, 23.0)
RectsView didSet frame: (40.0, 11.0, 240.0, 23.0)
RectsView didSet rectSize: 10.0
RectsView didSet rectSpacing: 15.0
RectsView didSet rowSpacing: 20
RectsView didSet rectsCount: 35
RectsView get intrinsicContentSize: 79.0
RectsView willSet bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 23.0)
RectsView didSet bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 350.0, 79.33333333333333)
RectsView layoutSubviews
RectsView layoutSubviews

MyLabel willSet frame: (-116.5, -9.5, 233.0, 19.0)
MyLabel didSet frame: (53.0, 13.0, 233.0, 19.0)
MyLabel willSet text: (53.0, 13.0, 233.0, 19.0)
MyLabel didSet text: (53.0, 13.0, 233.0, 19.0)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (65536.0, 20.333333333333332)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (675.0, 20.333333333333332)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (65536.0, 20.333333333333332)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (338.0, 40.666666666666664)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (65536.0, 20.333333333333332)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (65536.0, 20.333333333333332)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (338.0, 40.666666666666664)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (65536.0, 20.333333333333332)
MyLabel get intrinsicContentSize: (338.0, 40.666666666666664)
MyLabel willSet bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 233.0, 19.0)
MyLabel didSet bounds: (0.0, 0.0, 350.0, 41.0)
MyLabel layoutSubviews
MyLabel layoutSubviews
```

When called for the first time `UILabel` returns a intrinsic width of `65536.0` is this some constant? I am only aware of `UIView.noIntrinsicMetric = -1` which specifies, that the view does not have a instrinsic size in the given dimension.

Why, is `intrinsicContentSize` called multiple times on `UILabel`? I tried to return the same size `(65536.0, 20.333333333333332)` in `RectsView` but this does not make any difference, `intrinsicContentSize` is still only called once.

In the last call to `intrinsicContentSize` of `UILabel` the value `(338.0, 40.666666666666664)` is returend. It seems that `UILabel` know at this point, that it will be re-sized to a width of `350`, **but how?**

Another oberservation is, that on both views `intrinsicContentSize` is NOT called **after** `bounds.didSet`. Thus there has to be a way to know the upcomming frame changes in `intrinsicContentSize` **before** `bounds.didSet`. **How?**

**UPDATE 2:**

I have added debug output to following, other `UILabel` methods as well, but they are **not** called (thus seem not to influence the problem):

```
sizeToFit()
sizeThatFits(_ :)
contentCompressionResistancePriority(for :)
contentHuggingPriority(for :)
systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ :)
systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ :, withHorizontalFittingPriority :, verticalFittingPriority:)
preferredMaxLayoutWidth  get + set
```

Comment: Have you tried calling 'invalidateIntrinsicContentSize' in the 'layoutSubviews' method? This will allow you to recalculate the intrinsicContentSize when the view changes size.

Answer (score 1):

As @DonMag suggested I used a Technical Support Incident to get a feedback directly from an Apple engineer. It took some time to get an answer but eventually it arrived:

**Long story short:** Do not use intrinsic size

It seems that intrinsic size is more a less an internal feature which is not intended to be used by custom views. Of course it is not a private API and can be uses. However, without (many) being uses along side with other private iOS features it is pretty limited and can hardly be used.

Apple suggested to use AutoLayout and constraints instead. Even for such a basic example as a custom UILabel clone.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question: [UITableViewCell with intrinsic height based on width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65775159/uitableviewcell-with-intrinsic-height-based-on-width) which seems to be a similar issue.

That solution was to override `systemLayoutSizeFitting(...)` in the cell class. Seems to work for your case -- with a necessary change in `RectsView` to re-calculate when `bounds` changes.

See how this behaves for you:

```
@IBDesignable class RectsView: UIView {
    
    // calcContent needs to be called
    //  when any of these values are changed
    
    // Properties which determin the intrinsic height
    @IBInspectable public var rectSize: CGFloat = 20 {
        didSet {
            calcContent(bounds.width)
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable public var rectSpacing: CGFloat = 10 {
        didSet {
            calcContent(bounds.width)
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable public var rowSpacing: CGFloat = 5 {
        didSet {
            calcContent(bounds.width)
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable public var rectsCount: Int = 20 {
        didSet {
            calcContent(bounds.width)
        }
    }
    
    // Calculte the content and its height
    private var rects = [CGRect]()
    
    // using newWidth parameter allows us to
    //  pass the new bounds width when
    //  the bounds is set
    func calcContent(_ newWidth: CGFloat) {
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        var y: CGFloat = 0
        
        rects = []
        if rectsCount > 0 {
            for i in 0..<rectsCount {
                let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: rectSize, height: rectSize)
                rects.append(rect)
                
                x += rectSize + rectSpacing
                if x + rectSize > newWidth && i < rectsCount - 1 {
                    x = 0
                    y += rectSize + rowSpacing
                }
            }
        }
        
        height = y + rectSize
        
        // need to trigger draw()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    // Intrinsic height
    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 10 {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: height)
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    // Drawing
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        
        for rect in rects {
            context?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            context?.fill(rect)
        }
        
        let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)]
        let text = "\(height)"
        
        text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), withAttributes: attrs)
    }
    
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        willSet {
            calcContent(newValue.width)
        }
    }
}

// Simple cell holing an intrinsic rectsView
class IntrinsicCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var rectsView: RectsView!
    
    var rectSize: CGFloat {
        get { return rectsView.rectSize }
        set { rectsView.rectSize = newValue }
    }
    
    var rectSpacing: CGFloat {
        get { return rectsView.rectSpacing }
        set { rectsView.rectSpacing = newValue }
    }
    
    var rowSpacing: CGFloat {
        get { return rectsView.rowSpacing }
        set { rectsView.rowSpacing = newValue }
    }
    
    var rectsCount: Int {
        get { return rectsView.rectsCount }
        set { rectsView.rectsCount = newValue }
    }
    
    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
        //force layout of all subviews including RectsView, which
        //updates RectsView's intrinsic height, and thus height of a cell
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        //now intrinsic height is correct, so we can call super method
        return super.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: horizontalFittingPriority, verticalFittingPriority: verticalFittingPriority)
    }
    
}

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    let CellId = "CellId"
    
    // Dummy content with different values per row
    var data: [(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, Int)] = [
        (10.0, 15.0, 13.0, 35),
        (20.0, 10.0, 16.0, 28),
        (30.0, 5.0, 19.0, 21),
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "IntrinsicCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellId)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellId, for: indexPath) as! IntrinsicCell
        
        // Dummy content with different values per row
        cell.rectSize = data[indexPath.row].0     // CGFloat((indexPath.row+1) * 10)
        cell.rectSpacing = data[indexPath.row].1  // CGFloat(20 - (indexPath.row+1) * 5)
        cell.rowSpacing = data[indexPath.row].2   // CGFloat(10 + (indexPath.row+1) * 3)
        cell.rectsCount = data[indexPath.row].3   // (5 - indexPath.row) * 7
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    // Add/remove content when tapping on a row
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        var rowData = data[indexPath.row]
        rowData.3 = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? rowData.3 + 5 : rowData.3 - 5)
        data[indexPath.row] = rowData
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Yes, that would be a work-around... although, if it solves the issue, maybe not such a bad thing.

As you've noted, `UILabel` can re-calculate its `intrinsicContentSize` correctly based on the final width -- which doesn't seem to be available in time for the way this code is written.

Take a look at `UILabel.h` (search for iOS runtime headers), and you'll see a lot of things "under-the-hood" that we're not privy to.

Comment: Thanks again for answer and your great engagement! You seem to be the IntrinsicContentSize Expert here :-) Adding `systemLayoutSizeFitting(...)` to the cell class indeed solves the problem. In my first tests everything worked fine. However, this seems to be a workaround instead of a real solution. When using a `UILabel` inside the Cell instead of `RectsView` everything works fine without any extra hacking. Thus the main question is still unsolved: **How does `UILabel` manage to set the intrinsic size correctly WITHOUT any external help**

Comment: @AndreiHerford - It seems like we're missing something fundamental here... this might be a better question for an Apple engineer.

Comment: Glad to know that I am not the only one not seeing how this is expected to work :-) My experiences with the Apple Developer Forum and their technical support is too good, but I will try reach someone over there as well.

Comment: @AndreiHerford - if you don't get anything from the Dev Forum, might be time to use a Technical Support Incident (TSI).